# Is there any danger of assigning a const char* to a string?

Tags: c++, string, initialization

I am basically assigning a const char* value to a string.
I am checking for a condition and setting the string to be empty as a default value.

In the parameterised constructor I am setting the string to be empty as follows

`ClassName:: ClassName(X x, string name):X(x), name(){}`

I set the string empty once I am done using it as

```
name="";
```

Is the above approach of initialisation correct?

Also is there any risk of assigning a const char* to a string?

```
const char* diag;
string name;

name= diag;
```

Comment: `name="";` is superfluous. _"Also is there any risk of assigning a const char* to a string?"_ No.

Comment: No, there's no risk. `string` uses a `const char *` as its reference.

Comment: You should read about std::string - specifically, [string::operator=](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/). When assigning a char array to a string, it copies it to the string, as per that page. Thus, that's safe, as long as the char* is null-terminated.

Comment: No, there is no problem here, `std::basic_string<CharT>` has an `operator=` overloaded for `const CharT*`, so as `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>` this is fine! Also, in general, if you want to clear an STL container, I would recommend using the `clear()` function that they provide.

Comment: So, your class has a data member named name, and your constructor takes an argument of type string named name, but it ignores that argument, and sets name to an empty string?

Comment: Basically the const char* here is a value being returned by a function. const char* diagName(const char* name); I want to set this value being returned by the function to the string.

Answer (score 3):

The class `std::string` has corresponding constructors and assignment operators for objects of type `char *`. The only problem that can arise relative to the objects of this type is when the initializer is a null pointer.

Take into account that if there is declared a variable like this

```
const char *name = "";
```

then `name` is not a null pointer. It is a pointer to the first character (character `'\0'`) of an array of type `const char[1]` that corresponds to the "empty" string literal and that has the static storage duration.

If you write for example

```
std::strig s( name );
```

or

```
std::string s = name;
```

then you will get an empty object `s` of type `std::string` becsuse there is nothing to copy from the "empty" string literal.

Thus it does not make sense to declare objects of type `std::string` such a way. It is enough to write

```
std::string s;
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nevertheless the Standard says that the initializer shall not be a null pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: According to this reference, the null pointer is an undefined behavior: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And what?

Answer (score 0):

In your example there isn't a problem, but in general you need to know that the array of characters pointed to by the `const char *` is null-terminated, otherwise the std::string constructor will keep reading memory past the end of the array.